# Problem with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am encountering a problem when using LINQ in C#, I am constantly getting "Specified cast is not valid". This is what I am trying to do.

I create a class in which I declare all the columns of the table.

```
    [Table(Name="tbl_Aff")]
    public class Affiliate 
    {
        [Column]
        public string name;
        [Column]
        public string firstname;
        [Column]
        public string surname;
        [Column]
        public string title;
    }
```

I then declare a strongly typed DataContext in which I declare all Table collections as members of the context.

```
    public partial class Database : DataContext 
    {
        public Table<Affiliate> affiliate;

        public Database() : base(Settings.getConnectionString()) { } //This method gets the connection string by reading from an XML file.
    }
```

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Database database = new Database();

            try
            {
                var q = from a in database.affiliate
                        select a;

                foreach (var aff in q) // Here I get the error "Specified cast is not valid"
                {
                    lblMessage.InnerHtml += aff.name + "
";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Table<T>` is a generic class - but your code appears to be declaring a variable of type `Table`. What's the exact type of `affiliate`? Also, what does the cast exception say in terms of what it's trying to cast from/to?

Comment: I have just edited my code forgot to format the code, sry. Table<T> is of type class Affiliate Table<Affiliate>. As regards to what the cast exception say, it says only "Specified cast is not valid" and nothing else.. Maybe I should catch the error in a different exception?

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at Read_Affiliate(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at new_signup.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\m.buhagiar\Desktop\Signup_Solution\signupLogic\new_signup\Default.aspx.cs:line 28

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetInt32()` suggests that at least one of the columns of `tbl_Aff` is not actually a string (`[n]varchar(...)`/`[n]text`), and you haven't given it any hints. The simplest trick here is to simply hake that property an `int` (since that is what it clearly wants).

I'm also wondering if there is more to `Affiliate` that you haven't shown; interfaces, base-classes, a separate partial class etc (as those columns look like they *should* be strings).

The main time this problem bites me is when I have (for example) a `tinyint` in the DB, and forget to type an enum accordingly (`: byte` in that case).

Comment: Thanks for this.. I have manually checked that all columns in class Affiliate match the data types declared in the database, and found out that I was declaring some columns as int instead of Int16. Thanks once again.